# Formatting the logs in specific format

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I am trying to format the log that gets generated every few hours. Below is the example and the code I tried. Please help me in getting the required format.

```
[28/Jul/2006:10:27:10 -0500] GET /cgi-bin/try/ HTTP/1.0 200 iphone-S
[28/Jul/2006:10:27:10 -0200] GET /hidden/ HTTP/1.0 404 iphone-X
[28/Jul/2006:10:27:10 -0100] PUT /users/98761/geo/ HTTP/1.0 504 iphone-6s
[28/Jul/2006:10:27:10 -0400] POST /users/12345/places/ HTTP/1.0 202 iphone-7P
[28/Jul/2006:10:27:10 -0100] PUT /geo/1234/places/12/ HTTP/1.0 202 iphone-8
[28/Jul/2006:10:27:10 -0100] PUT /geo/1254/places/12/ HTTP/1.0 202 iphone-7s
[28/Jul/2006:10:27:10 -0100] PUT /geo/1294/places/12/ HTTP/1.0 202 iphone-6
---SERVER RESTART---
[28/Jul/2006:10:27:10 -0400] PUT /cgi-bin/try/ HTTP/1.0 200 iphone-3
[28/Jul/2006:10:27:10 -0500] POST /hidden/ HTTP/1.0 404 iphone-7P
[28/Jul/2006:10:27:10 -0500] POST /hidden/ HTTP/1.0 404 iphone-6s
---SERVER RESTART---
[28/Jul/2006:10:27:10 -0600] GET /users/98763/geo/ HTTP/1.0 504 iphone-6s
[28/Jul/2006:10:27:10 -0700] GET /users/12345/places/ HTTP/1.0 202 iphone-6
[28/Jul/2006:10:27:10 -0700] GET /users/12347/places/ HTTP/1.0 202 iphone-6
[28/Jul/2006:10:27:10 -0700] GET /users/12367/places/ HTTP/1.0 202 iphone-5s
[28/Jul/2006:10:27:10 -0700] GET /users/12387/places/ HTTP/1.0 202 iphone-7s
[28/Jul/2006:10:27:10 -0900] POST /geo/12346/places/4/ HTTP/1.0 202 iphone-X
```

Desired output:

```
"""
verb        uri                 status    counts
GET         /cgi-bin/try/       200       1
GET         /hidden/            404       1
GET         /users/#/places/    202       4
POST        /geo/#/places/#/    202       1
POST        /hidden/            404       2
POST        /users/#/places/    202       1
PUT         /geo/#/places/#/    202       3
PUT         /users/#/geo/       504       1
"""
```

Code I tried:

```
$ cat test.log | cut -d ']' -f2- | sort |head -n -2
GET /cgi-bin/try/ HTTP/1.0 200 iphone-S
GET /hidden/ HTTP/1.0 404 iphone-X
GET /users/12345/places/ HTTP/1.0 202 iphone-6
GET /users/12347/places/ HTTP/1.0 202 iphone-6
GET /users/12367/places/ HTTP/1.0 202 iphone-5s
GET /users/12387/places/ HTTP/1.0 202 iphone-7s
GET /users/98763/geo/ HTTP/1.0 504 iphone-6s
POST /geo/12346/places/4/ HTTP/1.0 202 iphone-X"""
POST /hidden/ HTTP/1.0 404 iphone-6s
POST /hidden/ HTTP/1.0 404 iphone-7P
POST /users/12345/places/ HTTP/1.0 202 iphone-7P
PUT /cgi-bin/try/ HTTP/1.0 200 iphone-3
PUT /geo/1234/places/12/ HTTP/1.0 202 iphone-8
PUT /geo/1254/places/12/ HTTP/1.0 202 iphone-7s
PUT /geo/1294/places/12/ HTTP/1.0 202 iphone-6
PUT /users/98761/geo/ HTTP/1.0 504 iphone-6s
```

I can use `uniq -c` to get the final count but, I am stuck at replacing the middle numbers with a `#` sign.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `sed` command uses `s!pattern!replacement!g` to perform a global search and replace. The search pattern `/(users|geo|places)/[0-9]+` matches `/users/`, `/geo/`, or `/places/` followed by a number. The replacement string `/\1/#` leaves the original word in place with the number changed to `#`.

```
$ awk '/^\[/ {print $3,$4,$6}' test.log |
      sed -r 's!/(users|geo|places)/[0-9]+!/\1/#!g' |
      sort | uniq -c
      1 GET /cgi-bin/try/ 200
      1 GET /hidden/ 404
      1 GET /users/#/geo/ 504
      4 GET /users/#/places/ 202
      1 POST /geo/#/places/#/ 202
      2 POST /hidden/ 404
      1 POST /users/#/places/ 202
      1 PUT /cgi-bin/try/ 200
      3 PUT /geo/#/places/#/ 202
      1 PUT /users/#/geo/ 504
```

If you want the exact output format you gave you can use `column` to align the data into neat columns.

```
$ awk '/^\[/ {print $3,$4,$6}' test.log |
      sed -r 's!/(users|geo|places)/[0-9]+!/\1/#!g' |
      sort | uniq -c |
      { echo 'verb uri status count'; awk '{print $2,$3,$4,$1}' } |
      column -t
verb  uri               status  count
GET   /cgi-bin/try/     200     1
GET   /hidden/          404     1
GET   /users/#/geo/     504     1
GET   /users/#/places/  202     4
POST  /geo/#/places/#/  202     1
POST  /hidden/          404     2
POST  /users/#/places/  202     1
PUT   /cgi-bin/try/     200     1
PUT   /geo/#/places/#/  202     3
PUT   /users/#/geo/     504     1
```

Comment: Thank you so much John, I really appreciate your help. I have few questions,  
 1) awk '/^[/ : (Does this means modify pick line that starts with "[" )??.      2) In the sed command why did you use "!" and "+!", I know as we usually use sed 's/pattern/replace/g'.

Comment: 1) Yep. 2) It's cause I use `/` inside the search and replace patterns. To avoid escaping them I used `s!` instead of `s/`. It turns out `s` can take pretty much any character as a delimiter; `s/` is a convention, not a requirement.